# WPF DrawingContext seems ignore SnapToDevicePixels

Tags: wpf, graphics, antialiasing

I'm drawing a chart by direct calls to `DrawLine` on the `DrawingContext`. Since I want to avoid any anti aliasing feature, I tryed to put the SnapToDevicePixels=true on the parent UIElement, but I still have anti-alias:

[image]

The project was an old OS project not written for WPF4, but I retarget it to the Framework4, can this be an issue too ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SnapsToDevicePixels works only for element bounding box. You need to use [Guidelines](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html) with DrawingContext. Also you can specify [VisualXSnappingGuidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualysnappingguidelines.aspx) and [VisualYSnappingGuidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualxsnappingguidelines.aspx) if it fits to your requirements.

Comment: your suggestion works actually. In order to generate the proper guidelines I have to consider all the coordinates I will draw, and even add half the pen width. This generate a really messy code ( and is a nightmare to write such things ) Isn't there some shortcuts ?

Comment: @Felice Pollano: I found nothing :( Even framework classes use primitive solution "new GuidelineSet -> GuidelineSet.Add -> PushGuidelineSet". For example, have a look at OnRender method of the TickBar class.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually I'm looking at the result, don't know if its betetr with anti alias or not...

Answer (score 17):

I found [this link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-single-pixel-lines) where they basically say you should set

```
ParentUIElement.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

It worked for me, so it might be worth a try!

Answer (score 3):

`GuidelineSet` is designed to resolve your problems.

@Marat Khasanov recommended you to use `GuidelineSet` and you replied that it messed up your code. I'm also suffering from this problem, so I write the code below to solve this problem with non-ugly code.

**Notice:** This method works even in a `Viewbox`.

```
public static class SnapDrawingExtensions
{
    public static void DrawSnappedLinesBetweenPoints(this DrawingContext dc,
        Pen pen, double lineThickness, params Point[] points)
    {
        var guidelineSet = new GuidelineSet();
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            guidelineSet.GuidelinesX.Add(point.X);
            guidelineSet.GuidelinesY.Add(point.Y);
        }
        var half = lineThickness / 2;
        points = points.Select(p => new Point(p.X + half, p.Y + half)).ToArray();
        dc.PushGuidelineSet(guidelineSet);
        for (var i = 0; i < points.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
        {
            dc.DrawLine(pen, points[i], points[i + 1]);
        }
        dc.Pop();
    }
}
```

Call the method in `OnRender` and pass line points to it.

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    // Draw four horizontal lines and one vertical line.
    // Notice that even the point X or Y is not an integer, the line is still snapped to device.
    dc.DrawSnappedLinesBetweenPoints(_pen, LineThickness,
        new Point(0, 0), new Point(320, 0),
        new Point(0, 40), new Point(320, 40),
        new Point(0, 80.5), new Point(320, 80.5),
        new Point(0, 119.7777), new Point(320, 119.7777),
        new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 120));
}
```

Here is the render result in a viewbox:
[image: snapped result]